# Compile Razor views into a single assembly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, msbuild

What is the least invasive way of compiling `.cshtml` views into a single assembly? By "least invasive" I mean something that doesn't require twiddling with Custom Tools, setting esoteric values in `.cshtml` files and things of that nature?

I tried `RazorGenerator.Mvc/.MsBuild`, but it won't compile. `RazorSingleFileGenerator` requires messing with Custom Tools, which I would like to avoid.

As a bonus point: can this magical tool, if one exists, be seamlessly integrated into an MSBuild pipeline?

Comment: `RazorGenerator.Mvc` is the *least invasive* tool out there.

Comment: Have a look at [this article](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/06/precompile-your-mvc-views-using.html), its a step by step guide to using Razor Generator